# Connection refused when using shell_exec

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a database using a script by `shell_exec`, but I'm getting:

> mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.

When using the script without `shell_exec` (example: by submit button) it works perfectly.

---

On the caller php file:

```
shell_exec('php /Users/Desktop/save.php param')
```

Called php file:

```
$a=$argv[1];
saveonDB($a);
```

I really don't know why isn't working when calling the function by `shell_exec`. The parameters are being passed correctly.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

I made the example simpler:

connection.php:

```
function connect()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname= "db";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    else{
        echo "connected";
    }

}

connect();
```

caller.php:

```
    echo exec ("php /Users/Desktop/connection.php");
```

When executing the connection.php directly, it says:

> "connected"

When executing from caller.php it stays:

> "Connection failed: No such file or directory"

Comment: `saveonDB()` is not a built-in function. What is its definition? You may have a situation where a connection socket is not found via shell_exec when the same connection would otherwise work with `new mysqli()`.  Please post more code.

Comment: shell_exec might not have the full shell environment you normally have. Check your paths you are referring to to see if all the files you access can be found.

Comment: code updated, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out what happened. It seems that when executing via `shell_exec` php uses `mysql.sock`. The connection port is different when using MAMP. Placing the port on the server name parameter fix the problem.

Thanks for all input.

Comment: Nailed it, tks!